# OpenLDAP - Make required attribute of superclass optional in objectclass

Tags: openldap

My OpenLDAP schema defines an `objectclass` which is a subclass of `person`. Let's call it `myPerson` for the sake of simplicity. Since `person` must have a `cn`, `myPerson` should also have one.

I would like to make `cn` optional for my `myPerson`. Is there a way to do that in an OpenLDAP schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `MUST` in a superclass cannot be overridden to `MAY` in a subclass. An object of a subclass of `person` must still be a valid `person`. If you don't want `cn` to be required, you'll have to pick a different superclass.